# jQuery Autocomplete with JSON

Tags: jquery, json

Is there any currently-maintained jQuery Autocomplete plugin that accepts JSON input from the server?

Comment: This is not answering your question, but with autocomplete you usually want it to be lightning fast. Receiving plain text from the server lets you cut down on response size and skip json decoding which will make results display faster. I would rather go with plain text one

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out this one?

http://www.codeassembly.com/Unobtrusive-jQuery-autocomplete-plugin-with-json-key-value-support/

Answer (score 0):

Well there is [Jquery autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) but it isn't fully polished yet. Still worth taking a look I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Currently jqueryui's Autocomplete allows querying from the server.
It sends a 'term' parameter in the querystring containing the user input.

You can see a demo in the documentation [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote).